# maven-release-plugin custom releaseVersion without SNAPSHOT

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

We configured release plugin with custom releaseVersion

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
      <configuration>
          <tagNameFormat>v${project.version}-${buildNumber}</tagNameFormat>
          <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
          <releaseProfiles>releases</releaseProfiles>
          <scmCommentPrefix>NOTASK</scmCommentPrefix>
          <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
          <releaseVersion>${project.version}-${buildNumber}</releaseVersion>
          <developmentVersion>${project.version}</developmentVersion>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

We are using build number plugin to generate a build number
`<format>BUILD-{0}</format>`

Our project.version is 1.2-SNAPSHOT and when releasing, version becomes 1.2-SNAPSHOT-BUILD-5.

Is it possible to get rid of SNAPSHOT from release version?

Comment: This is a contradiction: You're declaring your project to be in the `-SNAPSHOT` stage (via `project.version`) which is **prior to release by definition** but it is supposed to be a release? Are you talking about what's usually called a (snapshot) _drop_?

Comment: Using maven release plugin your version have to end with SNAPSHOT. Maven release plugin wont release if version does not end with snapshot. If you have version 1.2-SNAPSHOT it will be released as 1.2. However using tag name format and build number plugin, SNAPSHOT is not deleted from version.